# Cherry picking features

Tags: svn

I've inherited a legacy project that must remain in SVN.

Originally a branch was created for a new release and several bug fixes were made and deployed to a staging server. Several times the client asks for only bug 1 and 3 to go to production server which is causing us a lot of headaches.

What is the best branch strategy to allow cherry picking of bugs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have 2 branches: "trunk" and "production". Trunk would contain the latest version with all bugs fixed. Production will contain only the fixes requested for the production.

The development goes in trunk. Periodically trunk is selectively merged into production (you select which revisions to merge every time).

Comment: I was thinking of having trunk with the latest production release and using feature branches for each bug, too much work?

Comment: I think creating branches just for the purpose of possible merging them into production in the future is too much work. If a separate person or team is working on a bug and the bug requires many commits you might want to create a branch for this bug, but after the work is done, you merge it into trunk and do not use that branch anymore. That's how I would work.

Comment: Used @Andrej solution and created a branch for staging and another for production